# How to get actual time in offline-first app

Tags: mobile, react-native, react-native-ios, gmt

What would you recommend to get the GMT time in mobile application even if the user change his/her local time zone or time manually? In my app, users may take offline actions and I should record actualization time of these actions. Since this app is being used where cellular reception is low, this problem produces another consistency issues.

Any idea would matter.

Comment: Are you asking about `Android`, `iOS` or `React`?

Comment: @Boken I think if he's asking for a `React Native` solution it has to be cross-platform

Comment: Any solution could be ported to React Native. This is a problem on every platform.